# What did Edith/Sydney whisper in Irving's ear?

Tags: dialogue, american-hustle

What did Edith/Sydney whisper in Irving's ear when she barged into the meeting at the casino in *American Hustle*?

Comment: She said *"Sandra will never know what I'm saying right now."* (In other words, we're not supposed to know. It's open to interpretation.)

Comment: wouldn't it be that his wife was canoodlng with a mob guy from Florida?

Comment: https://secure.sonypictures.com/movies/academy/media/americanhustle-screenplay.pdf

Answer (score 1):

#### TL;DR

> We need to talk! This is serious.

#### Context:

Carmine, Richie, the Sheik and Irving enter the back room of the Casino. Edith / Sydney stays at the bar to keep an eye on Rosalyn (who flirts with mafioso Pete).
Then Edith / Sydney walks over to Rosalyn and they go to the bathroom.

Here's the scene and at around 2:19 min (right after De Niro), you see Edith / Sydney entering the back room and whispering into Irving's ear.

According to the [script](https://www.imsdb.com/scripts/American-Hustle.html) (130):

```
130   SYDNEY RUNS INTO BACK ROOM, URGENTLY JOINS IRV AND RICHIE AT THE TABLE.

                          EDITH GREENSLY
                We need to talk! This is serious.
```

The scene ends afterwards and you see Carmine and Dolly climb on stage.